# existence of double covering

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $M$ be a manifold , and $\pi_1(M)=\mathbb{Z}$. then can we say, the double covering of $M$ exists and is unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classification theorem for covering maps says that coverings corresponds to subgroups of fundamental group, and what's more, $n$-fold coverings correspond to subgroups of index $n$. Now, does $\mathbb{Z}$ contain a subgroup of index $2$?

Comment: I had seen in a book , because fundamental group of  $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ so t has unique double cover but I couldn't undrestand

Comment: $GL(n, {\bf C})$ has the homotopy type of $U(n)$ which has the same fundamental group as $U(1)$ (this isomorphism is induced by $\det: U(n) \to U(1)$ and backwards by the inclusion $U(1) \to U(n)$ as scalars).